# Is the SIM900 3G? Or is the SIM900A able to connect to 3G?

Tags: shields, gsm, communication

I would like to state that I am not familiar with the whole cellular connection thing. But I was wondering if the SIM900/or/SIM900A is 3G and will work with [PTel Mobile](http://www.ptel.com).

I need this Arduino to be able to travel and needs to connect to every PTel's tower. Will I be able to connect to 3G or only the 2G and the 1G networks?

Comment: Do you need 3G, or do you just need Data? Arduinos don't run fast enough to even saturate 2G.

Comment: It's GPRS only (GPRS class 10: max. 85.6 kbps) according to the [datasheet](http://www.propox.com/download/docs/SIM900.pdf)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, but this is a comment for both your answers, TP Ap and Ralph. What is the source for your answers? I'm trying to find out the answer to this question myself and I've seen a lot of claims like yours which aren't backed up by sources. I haven't found a single source which confirms this one way or another. I read the datasheet for the chip and couldn't find the answer there either.

Comment: Find the proper [SIMCom module here](https://www.simcom.com/module.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if you are in USA you cannot use SIM 900A since it supports only Dual frequency bands.(900,1800 MHz)it supports only Asian region countries.

According to [Wikipedia, PTel Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_mobile_virtual_network_operators) supports only GSM 850/1900 frequencies. 
so SIM 900 supports( 850,900,1800,1900 MHz ) you must use SIM900

Considering about the speed you cannot obtain 3g, 4g speed since GSM Shield(SIM900) provides maximum of [GPRS class 10: max. 85.6 kbps (downlink)](http://www.simcom.eu/index.php?m=termekek&prime=1&sub=40&id=0000000147&page=1) so,

It will able to connect but cannot get such speed in 3g and 4g.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be able to connect to a 3G or 4G network. There has to be a 2G network / support and that support is getting less.